# Having trouble connecting ssh to linux

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, centos, vmware

I am only starting to learn how to use linux but I cannot connect ssh to my virtual linux installed through VMware. I tried pinning 192.168.211.132 from my windows but it shows request timed out. I changed the Internet setting to Bridged but the issue sustains. I also checked that my firewall is inactive. I simply have no idea what is going on here. The Internet of my linux is working fine since I can browse through firefox.

Also I should mention that the ip address of my windows also starts with 192.168.

[image]

Comment: on your windows what is your IP ?

Comment: ipv4 says 192.168.86.1, do they have to be exactly the same?@EchoMike444

Answer (score 2):

As you are a beginner, it would be easier to set the Linux machine to get the IP address from DHCP, then you would not need to worry about setting the IP address until you have learnt some more. You can get the assigned IP address from the Linux machine by opening the terminal (command line interface) and typing “ip address”

Otherwise, put the Linux VM in “bridged” mode for the network interface and if you Windows PC IP address is 192.168.86.1 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 then your Linux VM would have an IP address of 192.168.86.2 with a subnet of 255.255.255.0. Just make sure you check the IP address is available on your network before assigning it to the Linux VM by using the ping command, if you get a response, use another IP as that one is taken by something else!

Comment: So if I want to set a static ip to my linux, it has to be in the bridge mode?

Answer (score 1):

Your ens33 subnet mask is 255.255.255.0, which means that your Windows machine may be on a different subnet. Your Windows machine would need to have the IP address of 192.168.211.X to be able to ping the Linux VM

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say what I should do in this case. I changed my ip address of my windows to the same as the linux, but that messed up my Internet.

Comment: I tried ifconfig ens33 102.168.86.3 on linux but it still does not work

Comment: Check the following article. https://danielmiessler.com/study/manually-set-ip-linux/
You might have to configure gateway IP as well as DNS servers.